# Can't figure out an issue with Caesar Cipher in C++

Tags: c++, encryption, caesar-cipher

I have some trouble figuring out what the problem is with my code. My task is to write the Caesar cipher in a file. It seems to display additional symbols that should not be there (from time to time), but it is otherwise working well. Here is what it looks like http://puu.sh/kC04F/2fc1bbd048.jpg
and Here's the code, thanks in advance ^^

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<cstring>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  char ch[20];
  char conv[20];
  int i;
  cout<<"Enter a word "<<endl;
  gets(ch); 
  int otm;
  cout<<"Enter shift "<<endl;
  cin>>otm;
  int c=strlen(ch);

  for(i=0; i<c; i++)
  {
    conv[i]=ch[i]+otm%26;
  }

  for(i=0; i<c; i++)
  {
      cout<<conv[i];
  }

  FILE *stream;
  char ime[]="probe.txt";

  stream=fopen(ime, "w");
  fwrite(conv, strlen(conv), 1, stream);
  fseek (stream, 0, SEEK_SET);

  cout<<endl;
  fflush(stream);
  fclose(stream);


  system ("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's C++, what makes you think it isn't?

Comment: I tried that already, it gets even worse
http://puu.sh/kC0Lf/e92f9f0a81.png

Comment: Note that the letter 'a' has a value of decimal 97 in ASCII.

Comment: This line is faulty `conv[i]=ch[i]+otm%26;` so focus here. Is the input upper or lower case? Should there be brackets? What happens to a space or a number? `%26` asssumes you only have 26 characters.

Comment: When you used the debugger, what are the values in the variable that cause the grief?

Comment: When you are doing your math you are doing math with the "ASCII" value of that character. So you'll want to consult this: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Research the `isalpha()` function in your favorite C++ reference.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `char conv[20];` contains garbage.  Then you fill it up with the conversion but you never add a null terminator to the end to indicate the end of the string.  `cout` seems to be handling the garbage differently than `fwrite` so you get a difference on your output to the file versus what is on the screen.  To fix this change:

```
for (i = 0; i<c; i++)
{
    conv[i] = ch[i] + otm % 26;
}
```

To

```
for (i = 0; i<c; i++)
{
    conv[i] = ch[i] + otm % 26;
}
conv[c] = '\0';
```

Comment: The missing terminating zero is only one of many issue. The algorithm as a whole is broken...

Comment: Thank you so much, great explanation :)

Comment: @WhiteViking Yes the algo is broken but that was not the question was after.  I just wanted to answer why the output to the file had extraneous garbage.